# Finding coordinates of point on line joining two points at certain distance from one of points using shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I am new to GIS. The question I am going to ask has been asked before but it didn't solve my purpose. I am only using python and shapely. I need to find the coordinates of a point on a line joining two points at a given distance from one of the points. To help illustrate, I am including the following figure:

In the figure, I need to find **the coordinates (lat/lon) values** of the red points at a certain distance (say d1*1.01) from the point marked as C. Given are the points C, and P1,P2 and P3 with their coordinates in lat/lon format. How do I do find these values (lat/lon values of the red points) using only python and shapely. I don't want to incorporate Arcpy unless there is no other options.

[image]

Comment: Please always provide links to any question that you say has been asked before.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

My math might be off a bit but this should get you where you wanna go...

First, convert the lat-lon into x-y coordinate pairs (geographic -> projected CRS).  This allows you to calculate d1 using:

```
d1 = sqrt((P1x-Cx)^2 + (P1y-Cy)^2)
```

Then, create a vector which represents the line connecting C and P1:

```
U = [Ux, Uy] = [P1x-Cx, P1y-Cy]
```

Then, scale this vector by the desired proportion of d1 (a):

```
a = d1*scalingFactor

V = aU = [a*Ux, a*Uy] = [a(P1x-Cx), a(P1y-Cy)]
```

Next, find the point R1 by adding V to C:

```
R1 = [R1x, R1y] = [Cx+a(P1x-Cx), Cy+a(P1y-Cy)]
```

Finally, convert R1 back into geographic CRS.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the points will be on the earth's surface to have a meaningful lat/lon values by this method.

Comment: Yes, for cases where d1,a are large and/or x,y is large (far from 0,0) the method is unreliable.  But in general, for small d1,a (with an appropriate CRS) this works pretty well. You _could_ modify this approach to instead model C and P1 as points on a sphere of radius 1 (rather than points on a plane), where d1 becomes the angle between the points.  Since the question is closed, check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulae) for more info.